# How to loop through and reference with an array in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have this array and it has an array with different number of elements.

var filtered = [Array(3), Array(1), Array(2), Array(7), Array(1), Array(1), Array(5)]

```
0: Array(3)

    0: {fixture: {…}, league: {…}, teams: {…}, goals: {…}, score: {…}}

    1: {fixture: {…}, league: {…}, teams: {…}, goals: {…}, score: {…}}

    2: {fixture: {…}, league: {…}, teams: {…}, goals: {…}, score: {…}}


1: [{…}]                         //1 element

2: (2) [{…}, {…}]                //2 elements

3: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]             //7 elements
```

I want to access the data inside through looping so I try to use this:

```
for (i = 0; i < filtered.length-1; i++) {

   for (x=0; x<filtered[i].length-1;x++){

    let league = document.createElement("div")
    league.className = 'league'
    league.innerHTML = filtered[i].x.league.name                //error occurs on .league.name
    parent.appendChild(league)

}}
```

and I get this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'league')
```

I likely am referencing it wrong but do not know how else to do this.

Comment: Please provide your arrays in JavaScript syntax, not as copy/paste from the console.

Comment: @trincot it is an API Call and I can't access the json

Comment: `x` is not the name of a property, but your index variable. So `filtered[i][x]`.

Comment: You can always do `JSON.stringify(myresponse)`.

Comment: If it's from an API call then you can get the original response from the browser tools network tab

Comment: Try to [].forEach function instead of for() loop